# Error while installing libtool on chocolatey

Tags: chocolatey, libtool

I am trying to install `libtool` on chocolatey. However, I am getting an error...

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>choco install libtool
Chocolatey v0.10.15
Installing the following packages:
libtool
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
libtool not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
 Source(s): 'https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/'
 NOTE: When you specify explicit sources, it overrides default sources.
If the package version is a prerelease and you didn't specify `--pre`,
 the package may not be found.
Please see https://chocolatey.org/docs/troubleshooting for more
 assistance.

Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - libtool - libtool not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
 Source(s): 'https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/'
 NOTE: When you specify explicit sources, it overrides default sources.
If the package version is a prerelease and you didn't specify `--pre`,
 the package may not be found.
Please see https://chocolatey.org/docs/troubleshooting for more
 assistance.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a `libtool` package for Chocolatey. There are no results when I search for "libtool" on chocolatey.org.

The GnuWin32 project has [LibTool for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libtool.htm). Also, Cygwin, MSYS2, and Windows Subsystem for Linux have libtool packages.